# Laravel 5.2 send password reset after registration

Tags: php, laravel

I have altered my authController.php file to do a few things needed for my project. It works great, just need to make one more change. Right now the controller looks like this:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Role;
use Mail;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins, ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/add';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);


    }


     /**
     * Overwrite the Laravel 5.2 standard registration 
     * so user will not be logged in automatically.
     *
     * @param  array  $request
     * @return Register
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        $this->create($request->all());

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * Extend password reset email to user for when registering
     */

    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateSendResetLinkEmail($request);

        $broker = $this->getBroker();

        $this->subject = "First Time User Setup";
        $broker->emailView = "auth.emails.password";

        $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendFirstTimeSetup(
            $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
            $this->resetEmailBuilder()
        );

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);
            case Password::FIRST_TIME_SETUP:
                return $this->getSendFirstTimeSetupEmailSuccessResponse($response);
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
            default:
                return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
        }
    }

    public function getSendFirstTimeSetupEmailSuccessResponse($response) 
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }


    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first-name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last-name' => 'required|max:255',
            'phone' => 'required|max:255',
            'form' => 'max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(Request $request,  array $data ) 
    {
        //Create the user
        $user = User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first-name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last-name'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        return $this->postEmail($request);

        /*
        Mail::send('auth.emails.registered', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) 
        {
            $m->to($user->email, $user->first_name)->subject('You Have Been Added');
        });*/

        //Is it a User? Then give them that role
        if ($data['user-role'] == 'user')
        {
            $role = Role::where('name', '=', 'user')->firstOrFail();
            $user = User::find($user->id);
            $user->roles()->attach($role->id);
        }

        //Is it an Admin? Then give them that role
        if ($data['user-role'] == 'admin')
        {
            $role = Role::where('name', '=', 'owner')->firstOrFail();
            $user = User::find($user->id);
            $user->roles()->attach($role->id);
        }

        return $user;
    }





}
```

It stops auto login on user creation, assigns a role to the user based on the form and sends a password reset email. The trouble is not I get the error `Trait method guestMiddleware has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController`

Answer (score 6):

One of the tricks to this is understanding how the `traits` inside of the `Auth` factory work.

First, we'll need to use the `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;` Trait as well as the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` and the `ThrottlesLogins` trait.

```
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins, ResetsPassword;
```

Next, we need to make sure that we have a `$request` instance being passed to our `create` method:

```
protected function create(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $data)
```

*Sidenote* - I would recommend moving away from passing in a `$data` object as an argument and instead working with `$request`. You can get your data like this: `$request->get('first-name')`, etc.

Finally, we pass our `$request` to the `postEmail()` function:

```
return $this->postEmail($request);
```

This will pipe the $request to the `ResetsPasswords\postEmail` function:

```
public function postEmail(Request $request)
{
    return $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
}
```

Which will inturn pipe it to the `ResetsPasswords\sendResetLinkEmail` function:

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateSendResetLinkEmail($request);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink(
        $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
        $this->resetEmailBuilder()
    );

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
        default:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Which will ultimately send out an email.

The key to making this entire thing work is that the instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` always contains an `email` field.

**Note**

The `response` that will be returned from the `sendResetLinkEmail` function may not be the same response that you sent out. Perhaps Users are confused by a `Password Reset` request when they've just created their account. Instead, maybe you want to send a `First Time Setup`. In order to do this, you will need to create your own `Password Broker` and `Password Facade`.

Next, lets make 2 new directories:

```
App\Brokers
App\Facades
```

Next, make a new file inside of `App\Facades` and call it `Password.php`. Namespace the file accordingly and extend the existing Password Facade. Also, we'll add another `const` as an observable response type for our `FIRST_TIME_SETUP`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades;

class Password extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password {
    /**
     * Constant representing a successfully sent reminder.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const FIRST_TIME_SETUP = 'passwords.first_time_setup';
}
```

Now we have added another response type that we can `switch` on which will help dictate how we send out our email.

Next, we need to make our `Password Broker` and establish our `sendFirstTimeSetup` functionality.

```
namespace App\Brokers;

class PasswordBroker extends Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker {
    public function sendFirstTimeSetup(array $credentials, Closure $callback = null) 
    {
        // First we will check to see if we found a user at the given credentials and
        // if we did not we will redirect back to this current URI with a piece of
        // "flash" data in the session to indicate to the developers the errors.
        $user = $this->getUser($credentials);

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return static::INVALID_USER;
        }

        // Once we have the reset token, we are ready to send the message out to this
        // user with a link to reset their password. We will then redirect back to
        // the current URI having nothing set in the session to indicate errors.
        $token = $this->tokens->create($user);

        $this->emailResetLink($user, $token, $callback);

        return static::FIRST_TIME_SETUP;
    }        
}
```

Now we need to copy the `sendResetLinkEmail` function that we saw earlier, and move it into our `AuthController`. This will allow us to modify the `Password` Facade that we use, and modify our `switch` statement to support our `First Time Setup`

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateSendResetLinkEmail($request);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendFirstTimeSetup(
        $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
        $this->resetEmailBuilder()
    );

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);
        case Password::FIRST_TIME_SETUP:
            return $this->getSendFirstTimeSetupEmailSuccessResponse($response);
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
        default:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Then, also in the `AuthController`, we'll make another function to return our `response`:

```
public function getSendFirstTimeSetupEmailSuccessResponse($response) 
{
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
}
```

Finally, if you want to override the `view` that is used by the function when being sent out, simply override the `$broker->emailView` property before invoking the `->sendFirstTimeSetup()` function:

```
//...

$broker->emailView = "emails.user.first_time_setup";
$response = Password::broker($broker)->sendFirstTimeSetup(
    $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
    $this->resetEmailBuilder()
);

//...
```

If you want to change the `subject` of the email, override the `->subject()` property inside of your `AuthController` prior to firing your `->sendFirstTimeSetup()` function:

```
//...
$this->subject = "First Time User Setup";
$broker->emailView = "emails.user.first_time_setup";
$response = Password::broker($broker)->sendFirstTimeSetup(
    $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
    $this->resetEmailBuilder()
);

//...
```

I could go on and on, but I think this will get you going in the right direction. Hopefully it will help a few others as well.

Comment: This is the best explanation I have got and makes sense but now I get the error `Trait method guestMiddleware has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController
`. I updated my code.

Comment: @Packy You may need to override that function's usage directly. Have a look at the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers trait; you'll notice there's an interesting `use` statement... `AuthenticatesUsers::redirectTo instead of RegistersUsers`. SO you would do the same for your `guestMIddleware`.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused on how to "do the same for your guestMIddleware". Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @Packy `guestMiddleware` seems to be a function you've brought over (either due to Copy or otherwise). Unlike traditional `classes`, traits don't have relationships between each other.  So if a method exists in a previously loaded trait, you must override that method and tell the class to use that method instead of the other traits method. `use MyTrait::guestMiddleware insteadof AuthenticatesUsers` This will use the `guestMiddleware` method from your `MyTrait` instead of the `guestMiddleware` method from the `AuthenticatesUsers`trait.

Comment: Ya, that error says it happens at the top on `class AuthController extends Controller
{`

Comment: Okay, so I just ditched the AuthController and did this in my own controller and I got the first stock part working great!! When I added the other code, I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::sendFirstTimeSetup()`. I never saw where I change to my new Broker. It looks like it uses the same original Broker

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your trait collision issue by changing the `use` block to the following:

```
use ThrottlesLogins,
    ResetsPasswords,
    AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers {
    AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers::guestMiddleware insteadof ResetsPasswords;
    AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers::getGuard insteadof ResetsPasswords;
    AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers::redirectPath insteadof ResetsPasswords;
}
```

It's ugly, but it will fix all related collisions, thus allowing you to just use the pre-built Illuminate methods if you so choose.